# Installation error while Installing SQL Server 2014 Standard Edition

Tags: sql, sql-server, installation

I have tried to install Microsoft SQL Server 2014 Standard Edition and it is giving the error:

> TITLE: SQL Server Setup failure.
>
> SQL Server Setup has encountered the following error:
>
> Could not load file or assembly
>   'file:///F:\tutorials\Microsoft.SQL.Chainer.PackageData.dll' or one of
>   its dependencies. The system cannot find the file specified.
>
> Error code 0x84B10001.

How do I fix this?

Comment: Not sure this is the right place to ask this question!!

Comment: We need more information. What have you tried to solve the problem on your own? What OS are you installing on? Where in the installation sequence are you encountering this error?

Comment: Related question on Stack Overflow: [Error 0x84b10001 when installing SQL Server 2012 on a machine with VS2013](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21643363/error-0x84b10001-when-installing-sql-server-2012-on-a-machine-with-vs2013)

Answer (score 0):

To resolve this issue, make sure that the path of the SQL Server 2008 installation media does not contain a number sign (#) character.

Please try this link : 
https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/955666

Hope this will help you. Happy querying :)